# Lining up html elements in a row

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am using reactJS.
In this form I am trying to have a text field followed by a button to click to copy that text to the clickboard and a hyperlink that takes you to that website (if it's a valid website).

As you should be able to see in the screenshot the copy button and hyperlink don't line up well. One is lower than the other and colliding with other elements.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grPJy.png)

I want to be able line this up in a row - see my html and CSS below:
.html

```
<div>
  <div className="link">
    <InputField
      disabled={this.state.disabled}
      placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
      title={this.props.title}
      value={this.props.value}
      change={e => this.props.change(e)}/>
    </div>
    <div className="copy-button">
      <button onClick={(e) => this.copyToClipboard(e)}>C</button>
    </div>
    <div id="link-button">
      <a className="link-button" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href={this.props.value}>Visit</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

.CSS

```
.link {
    width:80%;
    float:left;
    height:35px;
}
.link-button {
    width:5%;
    float:left;
    padding-left:10px;
    height:35px;
}
.copy-button {
    width: 5%;
    float:left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    height:35px;

}
```

Comment: I put your code into a sandbox and it doesn't look anything at all like your snapshot.  Can you please create a [minimal-reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1):

At first, change a bit in your HTML structure. give a class name to the parent container. It will look like this-

```
<div class="parent_class">
   <div className="link">
      <InputField
         disabled={this.state.disabled}
         placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
         title={this.props.title}
         value={this.props.value}
         change={e => this.props.change(e)}
      />
   </div>
   <div className="copy-button">
      <button onClick={(e) => this.copyToClipboard(e)}>C</button>
   </div>
   <div id="link-button">
      <a className="link-button" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href={this.props.value}>Visit</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now, you can make them in the same row using the following CSS. make the parent display flex. it looks like this-

```
.parent_class{
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

as a result, each item is now in the same row. Now, you set a different width for an individual item. it looks like the following code-

```
.link {
   width:80%;
 }
 .link-button {
   width:5%;
 }
 .copy-button {
   width: 5%;
 }
```

you can also put other CSS properties also like padding, height, etc.

Comment: Thanks for this response - at first glance it seemed like it would do just the trick but adding this in does not actually change anything on my display. I am not experienced with CSS - could this be because of the CSS applied to other parent components?

Comment: have you set a parent class? Surely it will work. 

You can use an extra property to make it vertically center and that is- 
`.parent_classs{ 
   align-items: center;
}`

if it doesn't fix the issue, can you please upload your files on Github and share it with me?